# org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

```
@Query(value = "select  * from associate_mapping  inner join station s on associate_mapping.station_id = s.id \r\n"
            + "inner join shift sh on associate_mapping.shift_id = sh.id inner join line l on l.id = s.line_id \r\n"
            + "where 1=1 and l.line_name = ?1 and sh.shift_name = ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AssociateMapping> getOperatorRequirementByLineAndShift(String selectedLine, String selectedShift);
```

and  error are

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.validateAliases(CustomLoader.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and use code fences to format your code.

Comment: I would suggest update your query like this: `select  a from associate_mapping  a inner join station s on a.station_id = s.id inner join shift sh on a.shift_id = sh.id inner join line l on l.id = s.line_id where 1=1 and l.line_name = ?1 and sh.shift_name = ?2 `